# Why do I have trouble downloading add-ons for Firefox?

Tags: 10.04, firefox, firefox-extensions

I get the error message:

> There was an error downloading .

I am using Lucid Lynx and Firefox 11.

Two of the add-ons in question are Easy Youtube dowloader and Flas Video downloader.

Comment: The only thing i can think of is: see if all video-codec-plug-ins under: "Tools > Add-ons > Plugins > Find Updates" are up to date. If not update them all, especially flash and try to install the both plugins/extensions you mentioned again, to see if it works! Hope this resolved the problem. (Also see if they are compatible with your version of FF and OS on the FF plugin-site).

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Silverlight needed to be updated. Two others were unknown. After updating Silverlight (Moonlight) it was still out of date. Probably those plugins are not compatible with Firefox 11. Firefox is starting to suck.

Comment: I still run an older version of FF, so i can't say for sure if that resolves your problem at all, but i also updated silverlight, while looking up the steps i posted. You need to follow the silverlight guidelines in order to update it correctly, see http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/get-started/install/default.aspx

Comment: You can also look at the FF plugin-page for those two, to see if they are both compatible. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/easy-youtube-video-downl-10137/?src=api and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader-youtube/?src=search If you don't mind having an extra program process running for the same tasks, this tool is quite useful and efficient: http://flavio.tordini.org/minitube

Comment: It finally downloaded and installed Easy Youtube Downloader (EYD). The checking for updates must have worked somehow. At first EYD's dropdownlist did not appear when clicked, but I realised that it does not work if a video's ID, following the "/watch?v=" part of the URL, starts with an underscore character. Iw ill report that on the addons page.

Comment: Glad to read, that it worked out in the end!!

Comment: @GeoffreyVanWyk Glad to see that you have fixed your problem. Please do add it as an answer to this question and mark it as solved later on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I remember that I also had this problem on Windows when I was still using Firefox. My solution back then was removing my profile and making a new one.

In Ubuntu you can access your profiles by running the following command at the prompt: `firefox -ProfileManager`.